# Custom Twitter share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I want to share my website articles on twitter (content,image,title)!

but twitter doesn't show image articles, just show content in the box.

this is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  t = window.twttr || {};
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
  t._e.push(f);
  };
  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

**Button:**

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world" data-size="small">Tweet</a>
```

Meta tabs

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" /> 
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Article Title" /> 
<meta name="twitter:image" content="grobal.dev/theme/images/img_art.jpg"; /> 
<meta name="twitter:url" content="grobal.dev/article/detail/1051"; />
```

Comment: I can share the articles on twitter but I don't know how to show image the articles. I added more:
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Article Title" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://globalwatch.dev/theme/images/img_art.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://globalwatch.dev/article/detail/1051" />

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="imageurl"/>
```

Comment: Still can't show image :(
Do you know how to set an image to show the articles?